# Can we say that the columns of the given matrix always lies in its range space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Can we say that the columns of the given matrix always lies in its range space. 
For example, suppose we have a square matrix $A$ of order $n\times n$ then can we claim that its columns say $c_1, c_2 \ldots \in R(A)$.

Please help me to clear my doubt.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. There is always a vector that can be chosen to produce a column from $A$:

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix.  Let $c_0, c_1, \ldots, c_n$ be its columns.
Let $e_1, e_2, \ldots, e_n$ be the (standard) basis vectors.
Then $Ae_1 = c_1$, $Ae_2 = c_2$, and so on.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I understood now, how $c_i$ will lies in the column space of the matrix $A$. Many thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

Let's work over $\mathbb R$, the field of real numbers. Also, let's consider the elements of $\mathbb R^m$ als column vectors. If $A$ is a matrix with real entries and $n$ rows and $m$ columns, then $A$ defines a linear map from $\mathbb R^m$ to $\mathbb R^n$ via $\mathbb R^m \ni v \mapsto Av \in \mathbb R^n$. Here, we also consider the elements of $\mathbb R^n$ as column vectors. The range of $A$ is the subspace $A\mathbb R^m \subseteq \mathbb R^n$.

Now, $\mathbb R^m$ contains the unit vectors $e_j = (0,\ldots,0,1,0,\ldots,0)^T$ with $1$ in the $j$-th row and $0$ elsewhere, for $j \in \{1,\ldots,m\}$. Moreover, $Ae_j$ is just the $j$-th column of $A$. So we have that the $j$-th column of $A$ is contained in the range of $A$ for every $j \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$, as desired.

In fact, the columns of $A$ span the range of $A$ as a subspace of $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Its more elaborate. I have to accept only one answer. :)